# Gatling: Get cookie value with Gatling 2

Tags: scala, stress-testing, gatling

Hi I want to extract a value from a cookie and pass that cookie value as a parameter to the next exec(). I found some syntax which does not work for the new Gatling 2. Could someone please show an example?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answered on Gatling Goole Group: extract with a regex from the "Set-Cookie" header:

```
.check(headerRegex("Set-Cookie", "yourRegexHere").saveAs("attributeName"))
```

Comment: I have a question, I have been trying to print the attribute saved to a session using the syntax "${attributeName}" however it prints the literal string without interpolating. When I use the syntax session("attributeName").as[String] I see the correct value.

Comment: This is a static value, and I failed to see why it would help supporting dynamic values there.

Answer (score 0):

Gatling can deal directly with cookies. This copies the JSESSIONID cookie in the session from which it can be retrieved.

```
exec(getCookieValue(CookieKey("JSESSIONID").withPath("/ApplPath")))
exec(session => "JSESSIONID=" + session("JSESSIONID").as[String]; session)
```

See Gatling current documentation https://gatling.io/docs/current/http/http_helpers/